# Tank Auth can't register or login once uploaded

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

Ok so I successfully created my first codeigniter project and used Tank Auth for the CMS authentication. All worked fine on my MAMP installation and once uploaded to my host still works.

I then duplicated the files to a new project on my mamp installation and changed a few config setting (new database, base url etc) all works ok, Once this new project is uploaded to the server I cannot login to the CMS.

The form looks as though it submits but the login page just loads again. No errors are given for invalid username/password.

If you try and use the Register form the same thing happens, submit and there are no errors it just seems to refresh the page and no user is created.

Any Ideas on what to try as this is really frustrating! Its almost as if the tank auth library isn't working as there are no errors.

config->tank_auth.php

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Website details
|
| These details are used in emails sent by authentication library.
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$config['website_name'] = 'Project 2';
$config['webmaster_email'] = 'me@myemail.co.uk';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Security settings
|
| The library uses PasswordHash library for operating with hashed passwords.
| 'phpass_hash_portable' = Can passwords be dumped and exported to another server. If set to FALSE then you won't be able to use this database on another server.
| 'phpass_hash_strength' = Password hash strength.
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$config['phpass_hash_portable'] = FALSE;
$config['phpass_hash_strength'] = 8;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Registration settings
|
| 'allow_registration' = Registration is enabled or not
| 'captcha_registration' = Registration uses CAPTCHA
| 'email_activation' = Requires user to activate their account using email after registration.
| 'email_activation_expire' = Time before users who don't activate their account getting deleted from database. Default is 48 hours (60*60*24*2).
| 'email_account_details' = Email with account details is sent after registration (only when 'email_activation' is FALSE).
| 'use_username' = Username is required or not.
|
| 'username_min_length' = Min length of user's username.
| 'username_max_length' = Max length of user's username.
| 'password_min_length' = Min length of user's password.
| 'password_max_length' = Max length of user's password.
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$config['allow_registration'] = TRUE;
$config['captcha_registration'] = FALSE;
$config['email_activation'] = FALSE;
$config['email_activation_expire'] = 60*60*24*2;
$config['email_account_details'] = TRUE;
$config['use_username'] = TRUE;

$config['username_min_length'] = 4;
$config['username_max_length'] = 20;
$config['password_min_length'] = 4;
$config['password_max_length'] = 20;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login settings
|
| 'login_by_username' = Username can be used to login.
| 'login_by_email' = Email can be used to login.
| You have to set at least one of 2 settings above to TRUE.
| 'login_by_username' makes sense only when 'use_username' is TRUE.
|
| 'login_record_ip' = Save in database user IP address on user login.
| 'login_record_time' = Save in database current time on user login.
|
| 'login_count_attempts' = Count failed login attempts.
| 'login_max_attempts' = Number of failed login attempts before CAPTCHA will be shown.
| 'login_attempt_expire' = Time to live for every attempt to login. Default is 24 hours (60*60*24).
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$config['login_by_username'] = TRUE;
$config['login_by_email'] = TRUE;
$config['login_record_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['login_record_time'] = TRUE;
$config['login_count_attempts'] = FALSE;
$config['login_max_attempts'] = 5;
$config['login_attempt_expire'] = 60*60*24;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Auto login settings
|
| 'autologin_cookie_name' = Auto login cookie name.
| 'autologin_cookie_life' = Auto login cookie life before expired. Default is 2 months (60*60*24*31*2).
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$config['autologin_cookie_name'] = 'autologin';
$config['autologin_cookie_life'] = 60*60*24*31*2;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Forgot password settings
|
| 'forgot_password_expire' = Time before forgot password key become invalid. Default is 15 minutes (60*15).
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$config['forgot_password_expire'] = 60*15;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Captcha
|
| You can set captcha that created by Auth library in here.
| 'captcha_path' = Directory where the catpcha will be created.
| 'captcha_fonts_path' = Font in this directory will be used when creating captcha.
| 'captcha_font_size' = Font size when writing text to captcha. Leave blank for random font size.
| 'captcha_grid' = Show grid in created captcha.
| 'captcha_expire' = Life time of created captcha before expired, default is 3 minutes (180 seconds).
| 'captcha_case_sensitive' = Captcha case sensitive or not.
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$config['captcha_path'] = 'captcha/';
$config['captcha_fonts_path'] = 'captcha/fonts/5.ttf';
$config['captcha_width'] = 200;
$config['captcha_height'] = 50;
$config['captcha_font_size'] = 14;
$config['captcha_grid'] = FALSE;
$config['captcha_expire'] = 180;
$config['captcha_case_sensitive'] = TRUE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| reCAPTCHA
|
| 'use_recaptcha' = Use reCAPTCHA instead of common captcha
| You can get reCAPTCHA keys by registering at http://recaptcha.net
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$config['use_recaptcha'] = FALSE;
$config['recaptcha_public_key'] = '';
$config['recaptcha_private_key'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database settings
|
| 'db_table_prefix' = Table prefix that will be prepended to every table name used by the library
| (except 'ci_sessions' table).
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$config['db_table_prefix'] = '';


/* End of file tank_auth.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/tank_auth.php */
```

**UPDATE**: -

I have uploaded to another domain name yet same server and it works fine. This is obviously not a coding issue but if anyone could shed some light or have suggestions it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Typically it is hard to guess at what you are experiencing.  When you have problems you cannot solve, always start by looking at your web server logs to see any errors that are not showing up.

If no errors exist, add comments into your code in places where you *expect* something to happen (say a creation of a user, and make it log `creating user` or in another conditional location `skipped user creation, error bleh thrown`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer but none of the error handling was being triggered. I have solved this now and for some reason when typing `http://www.domain.co.uk` was resolving to `http://domain.co.uk` but the base url in codeigniter was with www.

Comment: you obviously have problem with your `.htaccess` file please take a look in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18636186/1564365) and use that one if needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

$config['phpass_hash_portable'] = FALSE;

read the comment above: 'phpass_hash_portable' = Can passwords be dumped and exported to another server. If set to FALSE then you won't be able to use this database on another server.

You cannot move from one server to another unless the config is set to TRUE. Moving to another domain name is the same as moving to another server.